# Storing files in project directory using Spring

Tags: java, spring, file

I am trying to work through Spring tutorials on file uploads. What I'm trying to do is have the file be saved to a folder within the project. The folder is called "files" and is separate from the src folder.

```
|bin
|build
|src
|files
```

I have this code which accepts a file upload:

```
public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name, 
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream =
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name)));


                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();

                //file.transferTo(); help?
                return "You successfully uploaded " + name + "!";
```

What I want to do is use `transferTo()`to move the file to the "files" directory. When I try the true path, or try some sort of relative path I get this error which is created in the web window I am uploading files in.

```
Failed to upload file => "uploadedFileName/directory" does not exist
```

I am not sure why the file name is being appended to the directory path. Any assistance on this is much appreciated.

Comment: I looked at http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#transferTo(java.io.File) and it seems that the method transferTo needs a prameter in input. What are you passing as destination file?

Comment: I am passing the name of the directory files as "..//files" or the literal path ie. "localhost:8080//project//files"

Comment: How do you run the web app? Java web applications are build into war files in the end (or directory in the same style called exploded war) - this is usually deployed to a web server and that is the location where the files gets actually uploaded

Comment: If you have the error stacktrace. Please share it.

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to save the uploaded file to the file `"uploadedFileName/directory"`, you are using relative file path. It's relative to the current working directory of the java process (java process, running your Tomcat Application Server or whatever appserver you are using). And that current working directory is not your project root. The following code:

```
System.out.println(new File(name).getAbsolutePath())
```

will print you the exactly path where you are trying to save your uploaded file.

To fix that issue you have to explicitly specify your project root:

```
File rootDir = new File("C:/Projects/myTestProject");
File uploadedFile = new File(rootDir, name);
file.transferTo(uploadedFile);
```

In real project you will want not to hardcode that `rootDir` path, but to retrieve it from some configuration file.

Don't rely to the current working directory of the application server. It could point to any directory.

PS that's out of scope of this question, but please be careful with saving data to the user-provided file names. Malicious user could post file with name `"../../../../../../../../SomeSensitiveDirectory/SomeFile"` and will overwrite that file unless you explicitly check that input parameter `name` for bad characters.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a file, you have to save it to another file.
You should use `File#createTempFile()` which takes a directory instead.

```html
<p style="border-style:solid; border-color:#FFFFFF;">
  <br>
    File file = File.createTempFile("upload-", ".bin", new File("/path/to/your/uploads")); 
  <br><br>
   item.write(file);
  <br><br></p>
```